# Accessing refs in React Native custom functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ref

I want to call a child component's function in a parent component. Here's my pseudo-code:

```
export const Child: React.FC<Props> = ({ onRef }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (onRef) {
      onRef(this);
    }
  }, [])

  function callMe() {
    console.log('Child has been called');
  }

  return <Text>Child</Text>;
}

export const Parent: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const childRef = useRef(null);

  function callChild() {
    childRef.current.callMe();
  }

  return <Child onRef={childRef} />;
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `useImperativeHandle` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) to call the child component function.

You can define your function like this in Child component.

```
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
  callMe: () => {
    console.log('Child has been called');
  }
}));
```

In addition, you should also apply `forwardRef` to the child component:

```
export const Child = forwardRef(props, ref) => {
  // component logic
});
```

Now you can call this function by creating a ref in the parent component like this:

```
const childRef = useRef(null);

function callChild() {
  childRef.current.callMe();
}

return <Child ref={childRef} />;
```

Comment: You also have to apply `forwardRef` to the child, otherwise this will not work.